# How to communicate with the MATE community for general questions?

Tags: fedora, mate-desktop, theme

I've been working on [updating Clearlooks](https://github.com/codespunk/clearlooks-f14) for the more recent releases of GTK3 using the old [Clearlooks-Phenix](https://github.com/iloveeclipse/clearlooks-phenix) project as a base. It's been a steady few weeks and I've had a good experience reporting problems as I encounter them to the GNOME project via [gitlabs](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk), with general questions through their [discourse](https://discourse.gnome.org/) platform; and Fedora through [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Fedora), with general questions through their [discourse](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/) platform.

The problem I'm having is trying to find a place for general questions for MATE. Bug reports seem to be done through issues on their [github](https://github.com/mate-desktop/). But were do I go for general questions?

According to the [community page](https://mate-desktop.org/community/) on their website:

> You’ll find lots of useful material on our wiki, but we also encourage
>   you to help improve it.
>
> https://wiki.mate-desktop.org/

But the link is dead and links to a bad Cloudflare gateway.

There are social media links for Google+ (no longer available) and Twitter (not a platform for questions).

There is a link to [#mate @ irc.freenode.net](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#mate) but I've sat in there for days with no response and seen almost no activity beyond a few other questions which were never answered.

Blog posts are aggregated on something called "[Planet MATE](https://planet.mate-desktop.org/)" but this is, again, not a platform or questions.

For forums there is a [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MATEDesktop) but this also seems to be a platform for announcing releases, similar to an RSS feed. There are a few questions posted on it but there is no community there to answer them.

There is also a list of distro-specific forums:
[Arch Linux Forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/)
[Debian User Forums](http://forums.debian.net/)
[Fedora Forum](http://fedoraforum.org/)
[Gentoo Discussion Forums](https://forums.gentoo.org/)
[Linux Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/)
[Ubuntu MATE Forums](https://ubuntu-mate.community/)

But this is completely fragmented. My question is specific to MATE and not any specific platform.

---

**My actual question for MATE is:**

There used to be a feature of GNOME Panel from GTK2 called "User Switcher" which added the name of the logged in user as a clickable button:

[image]

Clicking on this button on the panel would provide a context menu of various options:

[image]

I liked this feature and wanted to know if there were any options for getting it back. Maybe it's an optional package, etc.

---

This is a very MATE-specific question and not platform related. It is not a bug or feature request but more of a "where is it, was it removed, etc."

Where am I supposed to ask these kind of general questions about the MATE platform? Are they expecting distributions to handle these kind of general questions?

Comment: It is a feature request IMO: If this was removed, please add it back. If it wasn't removed, please document how to enable it.